# Different installation folder depending the "Use Shared Runtime" option selection

Tags: c#, deployment, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I have figured out that if "Use Shared Runtime" option is enabled (with "Use Fast Deployment") then an application is installing at "/data/data/" folder on device.

But if this Android option is disabled ("Use Fast Deployment" as well) then  an application is installing at the "/data/user/" folder which is hidden without rooting.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Is it ok? Which mode is preferred for release version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Shared runtime is used for debugging.

This function was used for APKs relying on shared runtime expect the runtime to be installed separately,

Uncheck that box if you are building distribution APKs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/app-package-size#fast-assembly-deployment

If you prepare to release the application and did not know which settings should be checked, you can refer to this link step by step.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows

Comment: @Denis Mishin You are welcome, if the reply is helpful, please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.